# Can't get osmium to run on command line in windows 10

Tags: qgis, command-line, osmium

I have installed osmium but when trying to run it through command line I get the error

`'osmium' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

This is usually caused by not being in the directory or not having the system variables path correct.  I have tried various ways of connecting with no luck.  I was able to use osmium before on windows but now I am stuck.

I need it to extract historical osm data

Comment: How did you install? Any instruction?

Comment: Using git as per the instructions.  https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/manual.html#installation

Comment: Well, it looks like the download doesn't include an exe file.  Kind of strange... Fortunately I have a backup of the tool that worked so I just copied that into my C: drive.  It would be nice to know how to install it without the file.

Comment: The download doesn't include an exe, git provides the source code only. Did you build/compile the exe as per the instructions? https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/manual.html#installation (the bit that says "*Follow the build and installation instructions in the [README](https://github.com/osmcode/osmium-tool/blob/master/README.md)*)

Comment: Yeah, these are very poor instructions that only software engineers can decipher.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that may work for you

- download mambaforge here
  https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/latest/download/Mambaforge-Windows-x86_64.exe
- while installing it, make sure to select to the "Add Mambaforge to my PATH environment variable"
- make sure all git bash/powershell/cmd instances are closed
- open up cmd as admin (press windows key, type "cmd", then right click on cmd and click open as administrator)
- inside of cmd, type "mamba install osmium-tool", press 'Enter'
- Osmium should be installed and available to use from anywhere in the command line! Just type "osmium --version" to verify the installation.

Alternatively,
I also have a build with the exe and required dlls all together, here... https://github.com/pango3001/Osmium_1_14. Then you can just add osmium as an environment variable in Windows and point it to whatever directory the exe is in.

Comment: is the tool you have on your github the same as "osmium-tool" from the conda repo:https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/osmium-tool ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes it is, but I see the one on Conda-forge is version 1.15, the one in my is version 1.14, shouldn't be a big difference. If you download the one from my github, you can just add it to the path just like you would with any other application and use it from any directory you are in.

Comment: thank you very much for the reply, will do :D